# My React site only show home page, all other pages not found after upload on live server

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My React site working fine on local server but when upload on live server it not work properly without homepage. I use homepage link, use .htaccess file on public folder.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

````
<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL} >        
     <Switch>
          <Route exact path = '/' component = { Index } />
          <Route path = '/index2' component = { Index2 } />
          <Route path = '/index3' component = { Index3 } />
     </Switch>
</Router>```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, add the below code in your .htaccess file and place it on your build folder. Hope this will solve your problem :)

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. It`s working nice by using your code